# Sphere-Ray intersection on GLSL. Different behaviours depending on device

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glsles

I've been trying to develop some shading code for rendering atmospheric effects on iOS devices. This GLSL code relies heavily on the sphere-ray intersection calculus which I implemented this way, based on http://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/minimal-ray-tracer-rendering-simple-shapes/ray-sphere-intersection

```
highp vec2 intersectionsWithSphere(highp vec3 o,
                               highp vec3 d,
                               highp float r){
highp float a = dot(d,d);
highp float b = 2.0 * dot(o,d);
highp float c = dot(o,o) - pow(r, 2.0);

highp float q = pow(b,2.0) - 4.0 * a * c;
if (q < 0.0){
  return vec2(-1.0, -1.0);
}

highp float sq = sqrt(q);
highp float t1 = (-b - sq) / (2.0*a);
highp float t2 = (-b + sq) / (2.0*a);

if (t1 > t2){
  highp float a = t2;
  t2 = t1;
  t1 = a;
}
return vec2(t1,t2);
}
```

The code has worked perfectly fine on my iPad Pro 9,7 and on an iPhone 6 both running iOS 10.0.2.

However, trying on an iPad 2 (iOS 9.3) and an iPad 4 (iOS 10) the function does not return the same (expected) results. On my way for a solution I also encountered a very strange behaviour of the glDrawArray() OpenGL command, that seemed to crash sometimes with seemingly perfectly valid and compilable shading code.

I've checked both platforms have the same precision for highp floats (27 bits) and also checked with small scale spheres. For example:

```
intersectionsWithSphere(vec3(0.0,0.0,2.0),vec3(0.0,1.0,-1.0), 1.0);
```

should return no intersections at all but it does.

I'm a bit newbie on shader programming and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check your pow functions. pow(x, y) is undefined if x is negative.

I'd like to think a compiler is smart enough to turn pow(x, 2.0) to x * x, but I wouldn't like to count on it.

Where the exponent is a constant integer as in your case, you'd might as well just do the multiplies yourself. Where it's variable you should do something like pow(max(0.0, x), y).

Can't be sure this is the issue though.

A crash in glDrawArray is likely to be a separate issue entirely and unrelated to shader code, it's far more likely that it's trying to consume vertices from some invalid buffer or memory location.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Definitely you were into something there, pow(x, 2.0) is definitely not the same as x * x and that seems to be at least part of my problem.

Comment: However, it seems that the resolution of the vec3 on highp float on old machines do not allow to compute with enough precision the intersections with the spheres.

Comment: Is it running on the fragment shader then? Unfortunately GLES2 devices don't have to support highp on fragment shaders and can just use mediump (in CPU terms, pretty much half precision instead of single precision)

Comment: Thanks @Columbo. I finally got the fix right. :)

First of all I had this issue with the pow() as you pointed out. This gave me some results as a very low quality highly-aliased ray-sphere intersection.

To the precision problem, I tried to rescale the entire scene, without any improvement. Secondly I rechecked that the precision on both platforms is the same.

In a desperate move, I took the calculations of the ray direction to the vertex shader and it magically worked!

Comment: So to this point I've come to two possibilites: 

1) either there's a problem on glGetShaderPrecisionFormat() as clearly there's a difference between performing some operations on the vertex shader and on the fragment shader. 
2) the interpolation of the varyings is not good enough on some platforms.